# Brief moment from Definition 9.30 from Rudin's PMA

Tags: multivariable-calculus, operator-theory

[image]

I have some problems with claim which is marked with red line.

**Claim:** Let $A\in L(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then $A$ is invertible if and only if $\text{rk}A=n$.

**Proof:**
$\Rightarrow$ We know that $A\in L(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $A$ is invertible then by theorem 9.5 we get $\mathscr{R}(A)=\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence $\text{dim}\mathscr{R}(A)=n$. Thus $\text{rk}A=n$.

$\Leftarrow$ If $A\in L(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\text{rk}A=n$, i.e. $\text{dim}\mathscr{R}(A)=n$. Also $\text{dim}\mathbb{R}^n=n$. Let $\mathscr{R}(A)$ has basis $\{u_1, \cdots, u_n\}$ then by theorem 9.3 (c) system $\{u_1, \cdots, u_n\}$ is also basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\mathbb{R}^n=\mathscr{R}(A)$ and by theorem 9.5 $A$ is invertible.

Is my proof correct? Can anyone check this please.

Comment: I'm fine with it. - Other than that, do you maybe have a relation among the dimensions of $\mathscr N(A)$ and of $\mathscr R(A)$ and of $X$ available?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Yes i know the following relation: $\text{dim}\mathscr{N}(A)+\text{dim}\mathscr{R}(A)=\text{dim}X$.